# Paypal Error placing order

Tags: checkout, paypal, magento2.2.6

I just setup paypal checkout system but after paypal payment window, 
it redirects me to store page to place an order to store the order in backend orders panel,
but when I press the button to place an order system gives me the following error

```
No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?If yes then please share i am facing same issue

Comment: i just enabled option shows checkout paypal button on product page and its gone...

Comment: above solution not work for me..anyone has an idea?